# About a potential Chinese version of the movie "Vom Suchen und Finden der Liebe"

Tags: translation, culture, movies

I have a question concerning the German movie "Vom Suchen und Finden der Liebe" which appeared in 2005 in Germany's cinemas ([cf. Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vom_Suchen_und_Finden_der_Liebe?wprov=sfla1)).

Did this movie also appear in China with a Chinese transcription, either in the cinema, as a DVD or in streaming apps?

I try not to be off-topic: So, I ask this question only to introduce the follow-up question: If so, what is the official translation into Chinese of the title "Vom Suchen und Finden der Liebe"?

For this question, if you understand German and in the case and only in this case that this movie never appeared in China, it also counts as an answer if you provide your own translation of the title.

In case there exists an official published translation and this translation is not word by word but rather poetic, as it sometimes happens in such situations, you can also provide both the official published translation and your own literal translation as well.

I tried to google this information but found nothing, unfortunately.

Comment: From Google translation, it translates to "关于寻找和寻找爱情" (About searching and finding love). I think you should close this thread if the only thing you want to know is "Yes, or No."

Comment: I want to know much more than yes or no. And your google translate translation is inaccurate

Comment: Your three questions: 1. Does this movie have a Chinese version? 2. If "yes", how the title was translated? 3. If "no", what is the will-be translation? The first is asking for a "yes/no" answer; the second and third are asking for "translation", which violates the rule of this exchange. On the other hand, if you provide your point of view to challenge the accuracy of Google translation, and invite/ask suggestions/comments, then your thread will become much more meaningful.

Comment: The google translation translation repeats two times 寻找 which hardly reflects the difference between "looking for" and "finding of". Just to add context... But honestly, translations of movie titles can be poetic, sometimes you can't recognize them anymore as translation in the usual sense. They are adopted to the foreign culture to be catchy for every audience. The question is about making an internet search in Chinese apps and websites I don't know so well as a foreigner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

《寻找爱情的下落》looks to be the most common translation of the film's title.

There's an official [Douban](https://movie.douban.com/subject/1439571/) page:

> 寻找爱情的下落 Vom Suchen und Finden der Liebe (2005)

---

The film, in its entirety can also been found on [iQiyi](https://www.iqiyi.com/v_19rrny7nw0.html?vfm=2008_aldbd&fv=p_02_01) under the same title:

> [image]

There are Chinese subtitles if you do wish to watch it.

---

There also seems to be a poster/DVD cover written in Chinese:

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

> Did this movie also appear in China with a Chinese transcription, either in the cinema, as a DVD or in streaming apps?

again, what’s your notion of “china”

the file did release in taiwan , with the title “尋找愛情的下落”, a dvd with the same title was released by the company 聯影公司 in 2009

https://www.cineplex.com.tw/h/ProductDetail?key=315121131633&productId=83481

https://www.eslite.com/product/1004143371898630

errrrr . . . here’s a link to the movie, with caption:

https://www.cn6y.com/vlc/164617-1-3.html

[image]

Comment: If you compare with the other answer, does this mean it was released both in Taiwan and China? I think Douban is a website from the mainland. Thank you for your answer. It can be hard to access such information if you don't know where to look. 

Comment: @Christoph, “released in taiwan”, well it implied a company buy the right to show the films in cinemas, in taiwan only, that company does the translation, makes poster, advertises . . . etc. factually, “that area” does not “respect” any intellectual property, one need to check throughly to find if this film was released in cinemas in “that area”. it’s very doubtful. so back to the basic, what’s your notion of “china” 

Comment: Stackexchange is not there to discuss politics But I only know how to read and write simplified Chinese, by the way